# About backface-visibility

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari

Using the following commands can prevent many problems while web developing for the iPad, iPhone iOS Safari browser, problems like animations flickering, `position:fixed` performance issues, scrolling issues, etc.:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform  : translateZ(0); 
-webkit-transform  : translate3d(0,0,0);
```

These CSS commands are recommended on the internet to fix bugs on the iPad Safari browser.
However, recently, I discovered there is a problem occurs whenever using any one of them. I don't know if anyone has noticed it yet.  When you pinch zoom on the webpage, normally anything will not reload or refresh, but when any one of the above CSS statements is made, while pinch zooming you will see some stutterings, and things turns white for a second, as if the background were gone, and then it loads back in square chunks.

This is a very annoying issue.  I want to abandon using the above commands, but both using them and not using them creates bugs.  Is it the case that there is no way to fix it?

Comment: It seems like you're treating setting those properties as a silver bullet. That may not be such a good idea.

Comment: yes I know,but mobile safari have too much strange issues that I never have on desktop

Comment: That doesn't mean there's one thing that fixes everything.

Comment: If there is no silver bullets , the vampires win .

Comment: Yah duh, havent you seen Twilight?... no but seriously; Safari on iOS handles touch events in a unique way, and since Webkit is itself open source but Safari itself is not, we don't have a lot of visibility into why this might be happening, since as a community we can't see the source code.

Comment: @FatDogMark Silver bullets kill WereWolves, Vampires are only weakened by it: http://www.gods-and-monsters.com/how-to-kill-a-vampire.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -webkit-transform  : translateZ(0);  to any elements the target element touches or goes over.

I had a wicked 1+ second flicker which also drove me mad debugging, that worked in my instance.